# Linq to entities select records based on subitems

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I can represent my entity model like this:

```
-> Devices
  -> Records
    -> DataValues
      -> DataField
        - Name
      - Value
```

I want to select Records based on:

- The Name of the DataField of the DataValue
- The Value of the DataValue

A Record has multiple DataValues. I want to retrieve all records which evaluate to multiple sets of Name and Value values.

Aside, I'm working with entity framework. I've been trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
Context.Devices.Where(q => q.SerialNumber == serialNumber)
    .Single()
    .DataRecords.Where(w => w.DataString.Prefix.ToLower() == "data")
    .SelectMany(e => e.DataValues)
    .Where(r =>
        (r.DataField.Name == "" && r.Value == "") &&
        (r.DataField.Name == "" && r.Value == ""))
    .Where(t => t.DataField.Name == "")
    .Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(y.Value));
```

Bad thing is that I already ran out of RAM on the SelectMany part...

Whatsoever, any of you got tips for me about how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have links back to parents exposed through EF, you should be able to offload more work onto your RDBMS if you run your query at the `DataValues` level, and constraint the parents, like this:

```
var res = Context.DataValues
    .Where(dv => dv.Record.DataString.Prefix.StartsWith("data")
              && dv.Record.Device.SerialNumber == serialNumber
              && (
                  dv.DataField.Name == "quick" && dv.Value == "brown"
               || dv.DataField.Name == "fox" && dv.Value == "dog"
              ))
    .Select(dv => dv.Value)
    .AsEnumerable() // <<== This will bring your data into memory
    .Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(y);
```

The above query does not bring data into memory until it's time to run the conversion of strings to double, minimizing the strain on memory of your system. This is different from your query, which brings all data for a specific device into memory, and performs its filtering there.

Comment: Doing it like this works like a charm. Thanks for the explanation! :)